# Django signal m2m_changed not triggered

Tags: django, django-admin, signals, m2m

I recently started to use signals in my Django project (v. 1.3) and they all work fine except that 
I just can't figure out why the m2m_changed signal never gets triggered on my model. The Section instance is edited by adding/deleting PageChild inline instances on an django admin form.

I tried to register the callback function either way as described in the documentation, but don't get any result.

Excerpt from my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed


class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 100)
    pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page, through = 'PageChild')

class PageChild(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, limit_choices_to = Q(is_template = False, is_background = False))


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender = Section.pages.through)
def m2m(sender, **kwargs):
    print "m2m changed!"

m2m_changed.connect(m2m, sender = Section.pages.through, dispatch_uid = 'foo', weak = False)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? Looking for the same answer.

Comment: This is fixed now (1.6)

Comment: Sometimes when I copy and paste code from another signal receiver I forget to update the function name and only one of them runs.

Answer (score 13):

This is an open bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16073

I wasted hours on it this week.

Comment: I can't believe this is still an open issue. 

headaches included.

Comment: Is this still an open issue? Can't believe it

Comment: No, it's not an open issue anymore. My reply above was from 2012.

Answer (score 3):

You are connecting it twice, once with `m2m_changed.connect` and the other time with receiver decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will help, but the following is working for me:

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    datalist = models.ManyToManyField(Data)

from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete, m2m_changed

def handle_flow(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.debug("Signal catched !")

m2m_changed.connect(handle_flow, sender=Flow.datalist.through)
```

Comment: This one is different from what the user asked.
What the original question was referring to was a scenario where he was using an explicit Model "PageChild" to specify the relation here.

Comment: Even without using the explicit 'through' argument this signal will fail if you use inline admin forms like StackedInline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but are you sure that you should use Sender.pages.through for this special case? perhaps if you tried `@reciever(m2m_changed, sender=PageChild)`

Note: if you have @reciever, you do not need m2_changed.connect(...) as @reciever already performs the connect operation.

Comment: I tried it with PageChild too, but didn't change anything. Problem is that neither of two ways to register the callback works, that's why I included both. :/